# Joomla don't see subgroups in the Articles tab (Joomla 4)

Tags: cms, joomla-4.x, user-groups, joomla-4, access

I set up three users. To make things easier, let's take the following names: `X`, `Y`, `Z`. Additionally, there are subgroups in the Registered group, let's call them `X_group`, `Y_group` and `Z_group`. User `X` has the rights of the Registered group and `X_group`.

I would like to grant permissions for an article, for example: number 1 for user `X` and auto exclude for `Y` and `Z`.

Also, in the next article, I would like to make an article possible for two groups to access. I searched on the internet but couldn't find an answer to my question.

[image: Access in Article]

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note the difference between "user groups" and "access levels".

Access Levels determine which users have access to certain views and features.
Said levels are assigned to usergroups.
Creating a child user group will inherit the access levels of the parent.

The dropdown you see on the Articles page is a list of access levels, not usergroups, so this is what you'll need to create.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!